# How to use AutoDesk FBX SDK to build a new FBX model

Tags: c++, fbx

How to build and export an FBX model from scratch ?I tried to draw a plane, but the exported model is empty! How to build a scene from scratch and export it ?

```
// Create an SDK manager.
FbxManager* lSdkManager = FbxManager::Create();
std::string newfile = R"(F:/fbxdata/test.fbx)";
// Create a new scene so it can be populated by the imported file.
FbxScene* newScene = FbxScene::Create(lSdkManager, "New Scene");
FbxNode* root = newScene->GetRootNode();
FbxNode* child = FbxNode::Create(newScene, "child");
{
    FbxMesh* pMesh =FbxMesh::Create(newScene,"mesh") ;
    pMesh->InitControlPoints(4);
    FbxVector4* pCtrlPoint = pMesh->GetControlPoints();
    FbxVector4 vertex0(-1, -1, 0);
    FbxVector4 vertex1(-1, 1, 0);
    FbxVector4 vertex2(1, 1, 0);
    FbxVector4 vertex3(1, -1, 0);
    pCtrlPoint[0] = vertex0;
    pCtrlPoint[1] = vertex1;
    pCtrlPoint[2] = vertex2;
    pCtrlPoint[3] = vertex3;
    pMesh->BeginPolygon();
    pMesh->AddPolygon(0);
    pMesh->AddPolygon(1);
    pMesh->AddPolygon(2);
    pMesh->EndPolygon();
    pMesh->BeginPolygon();
    pMesh->AddPolygon(2);
    pMesh->AddPolygon(3);
    pMesh->AddPolygon(0);
    pMesh->EndPolygon();
    child->AddNodeAttribute(pMesh);
}
root->AddChild(child);
ExportScene(lSdkManager, newScene, newfile.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `AddNodeAttribute` instead of `SetNodeAttribute`.

```
void AddPlaneTo(FbxScene* Scene) const
{
    auto* Plane = FbxNode::Create(Scene, "plane-node");
    auto* Mesh = FbxMesh::Create(Scene, "plane-mesh");

    Plane->SetNodeAttribute(Mesh);
    Scene->GetRootNode()->AddChild(Plane);
    Mesh->InitControlPoints(4);

    auto* ControlPoints = Mesh->GetControlPoints();
    ControlPoints[0] = FbxVector4( 1, 0,  1);
    ControlPoints[1] = FbxVector4(-1, 0,  1);
    ControlPoints[2] = FbxVector4(-1, 0, -1);
    ControlPoints[3] = FbxVector4( 1, 0, -1);

    Mesh->BeginPolygon();
    Mesh->AddPolygon(0);
    Mesh->AddPolygon(1);
    Mesh->AddPolygon(2);
    Mesh->AddPolygon(3);
    Mesh->EndPolygon();
}
```